# how do I use insertion sort on a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, csv

So, I made this code almost work, but I want to use insertion sort on the array and for the output to display results sorted by product ID only by insertion sort. Each product ID should have the same corresponding number of units. The units should not be sorted independently. The only order would be by product ID is what I'm basically implying.

```
      import java.util.*;
      import java.io.*;
      class newversion {
        public static int [][] table; // the output table
        public static int numOfRows; //number of rows used up in the table

        public static int lookfor(int productID){
          int location = -1; //-1 an error
          for(int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++){
            if (table[i][0] == productID){
              location = i;
            }
          }
          return location;
        }
      /*
        here is my modified bubble sort code. I based it on this, but done differently:

        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283655/bubble-sort-on-2d-array-java

        public static void swap(int int1, int int2, int[] array) {
          if(int1 == int2){
            return;
          }
          else{
          int temp = int2;
          array[int2] = array[int1];
          array[int2] = temp;
        }
        }
        but it didn't work and I had to try something else
      */
        public static boolean contains(int productID){
          if (lookfor(productID) == -1){
            return false;
          }
            return true;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
          File file = null;
          Scanner scanner = null;
          try{
            file = new File("data.csv");
            scanner = new Scanner( file );
          }
          catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error opening file!");
            System.exit(1);
          }

          //citation of idea for sorting method in 2D array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283655/bubble-sort-on-2d-array-java
          //I'm using bubble sort on a 2D array
          //this is his code
          /*


          private static void bubblesort(Integer[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
                if(array[j].compareTo(array[j+1]) > 0) {
                    swap(j, j+1, array);
                }
            }
        }

      }

      private static void swap(Integer int1, Integer int2, Integer[] array) {
          if(int1 == int2)return;
          Integer temp = new Integer(array[int2]);
          array[index2] = array[int1];
          array[int1] = temp;

      }
          */
          //here's my idea for bubble sort on a 2D array
      /*
          for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < numOfRows - 1; j++) {
              if(table[j][0].compareTo(array[j+1][0]) > 0) {
                      swap(j, j+1, table);
                  }
          }
          //this didn't work well either
          //Now, I have to try another for-loop
      */
           //Count the number of lines in the file
           int size_of_file = 0;
           while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
             scanner.nextLine();
             size_of_file++;
           }
           table = new int[size_of_file][2];

           //reset scanner
           try{
             file = new File("data.csv");
             scanner = new Scanner( file );
           }
           catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Error opening file!");
             System.exit(1);
           }

          //save the title
          String titleLine = scanner.nextLine();
          System.out.println(titleLine);
          //for each line in the file, store and total it.
          numOfRows=0;
          while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String ln = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] row = ln.split(",");
            System.out.println(row[0] + ", " + row[1]);
            if (contains(Integer.parseInt(row[0]))){
              //This is the location in the table where the product id exists already.
              int location = lookfor(Integer.parseInt(row[0]));
              //add the units to what we have in the table
              table[location][1] += Integer.parseInt(row[1]);
            }
            else{
              table[numOfRows][0]= Integer.parseInt(row[0]);
              table[numOfRows][1]= Integer.parseInt(row[1]);
              numOfRows++;
            }
          }
          //output
          try{
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("output.csv");
            output.println(titleLine);
            for(int i=0;i<numOfRows;i++){
                output.println(table[i][0] + "," + table[i][1]);
            }

            output.close();
          }
          catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error writing file");
          }
        }
      }
```

I want to understand how to use FileReader better. I read a little bit about it here:

https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-file-reading-and-writing-files-in-java.html
https://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/585814-reading-data-into-array-file

Although I don't think I understand from that how to store it into an array. Could someone explain how I can store values from FileReader class into an array? I want it in a 2D array where the number of rows is just however many product IDs I have and there is always 2 columns.

Excel File to read from:

```
Product ID  Units                           
10002   4                           
10004   6                           
10008   2                           
10010   3                           
10010   3
```

output I get right now:

```
Product ID  Units
    10002   20
    10004   72
    10008   12
    10010   37
    10007   28
    20003   42
    30019   56
    30020   29
    10006   36
    20005   32
    etc.
```

I apologize if this update should be posted as a different question. Let me know so I can go by community standards. The piece of output I posted, you'll notice isn't sorted by productID. That's the last thing I want to do. Other than that, it basically works. I am apologizing in case someone wants to vote me down for not posting the answer, since technically it would be the same answer to the initial question. If this update should be a different thread, again, let me know and I'll make the edit.

Comment: what is a in [a] in this line? Array[][] arr3 = new ArrayList[a][1];

Comment: a is the number of rows. I edited it so now its:

Array[][] arr = new ArrayList[int a][int b];
           FileReader filereader = new FileReader(Sales Data.xls);

Comment: so its one array and not three. I thought it was more efficient.

Comment: Multiple issues with your code, aside from the file reading stuff. [Here's](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/writeread-excel-files-in-java-example/) an example of file reading from excel, hopefully that helps